# A problem on associative property of logic and DeMorgan's law

Tags: logic

Consider the logic statement $$N_1 \land N_2 \land N_3 \land N_4 \land N_5 \land...$$If I were to write the negation of the above statement i.e. $$\lnot (N_1 \land N_2 \land N_3 \land N_4 \land N_5 \land...)$$
Is the result equal to $$(\lnot N_1) \lor (\lnot N_2) \lor (\lnot N_3) \lor (\lnot N_4) \lor (\lnot N_5) \lor...$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at DeMorgan's Laws we can negate a premise and it'll still be logically equivalent. For example:

$$\lnot (P \land Q) \iff \lnot P \lor \lnot Q \\ \text{The negation "flips" the $\land$ to a $\lor$.} \\ \lnot(P\land Q) \equiv (\lnot P \lor \lnot Q)$$

To your question, your reasoning looks correct.